# How to resolve the"The chunked cookie is incomplete" in ASP.NET application from Chrome and Edge browsers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, chunked-encoding

Our application started throwing the "Chunked cookie" exception and asked the user to clear cookies and cache which worked for a few days and again happened. Sometimes, this approach also does not work. We are not sure how to fix this one. We updated the OWIN-related libraries to the latest as well still the same? Any suggestion to overcome this issue since it is not allowing users to log in.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            CookieName = "CoreADLogin",
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            #if DEBUG
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44345/",

            #else
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            #endif

            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { ValidateIssuer = false },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() { AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed }
        });
```

Exception :

> System.FormatException:
>
> at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.GetRequestCookie (Microsoft.Owin, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
> at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler+d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage+d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext+d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
> at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication+AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication+<>c__DisplayClass285_0.b__0 (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)